# Hyperlink to a local file doesn't work

Tags: c#, hyperlink

I need to add 2 type of links to existing report with c#. For exapmle:

```
1) http://www.google.co.il/
2) file:///C:/index.html
```

I added the links, but only the **"http://" works**. when I press the link of **"file:///" nothing happens**.

I've uploaded the full project (very small though) which includes the problem:
http://www.filefactory.com/file/452gsoyymalv/n/ObjectReports.zip

BTW, the "index.html" is a simple 'helloWorld' which loaded successfully when writing the path on the address bar in the browser.

Do anyone knows what additional settings should be set to make the file link work?

*Credit for the sample (**without my case**):
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/reportviewerobject04172007111636am/reportviewerobject.aspx

Comment: What have you tried? Linking to local files is disabled in most browsers by default, for security reasons.

Comment: It's working if I copy-paste the link (in all browsers). It's just not working directly from my form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK this is disabled for security reasons - the `ReportViewer` is NOT a complete browser...

You can try to circumvent that limitation by handling [`ReportViewer.Hyperlink` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.reportviewer.hyperlink%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) yourself... can't try it myself right now, but that's about the only option that can possibly work IMHO...

Answer (score 1):

This is the detailed solution (main idea suggested by @Yahia):

First, I created the event handler:

```
public void HyperLinkReportHandler(Object sender, HyperlinkEventArgs e)
        {
            Process.Start(e.Hyperlink);
        }
```

Second, I associated the event handler:

```
this.rvContainer.Hyperlink += HyperLinkReportHandler;
```